# How to Add Basemap from ArcGIS Online to ArcMap 9.3?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-9.3, arcgis-online, arcgis-online-basemaps

I want to load a basemap into ArcMap 9.3 using "Add Data from ArcGIS Online" tools.

Does anyone know the URL needed to load it?

Comment: i am using ArcGIS 9.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the **[ArcGIS Desktop 9.3](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?id=532&pid=529&topicname=Accessing%20map%20and%20other%20contents%20from%20the%20ArcGIS%20Online%20website&)** Help:

> You can alternately make a connection to the ArcGIS Online ArcGIS
>   Server from inside your Catalog to access the key basemaps: In the Add
>   ArcGIS Server connection dialog, paste this URL into the Server URL
>   field: **http://services.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/services**. You can
>   then browse the services it contains.

The URL mentioned is probably the one you have asked for.

I just used the 9.3 instructions above at 10.2 to view the Ocean Basemap and they still work.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following webpage to add basemaps to 9.3.

[Esri Basemap Layers](http://www.arcgis.com/home/group.html?q=tags%3aArcMap93_Base&t=group&owner=esri&title=ESRI%20Maps%20and%20Data&sortField=title&sortOrder=asc&content=all)

If you click the Open link under each layer you can either save as a layer file or open in ArcGIS desktop

Comment: i asked for another method required to enter a URL , but yours it ok ! Great job .

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be through the "Add Data" button?

Referring to [This help page](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?id=532&pid=529&topicname=Accessing_map_and_other_contents_from_the_ArcGIS_Online_website), I would suggest visiting the basemap's ArcGIS Online page to add it to your map in Desktop.

It's been a while since I worked with 9.3 but couldn't you add the basemap as a service in ArcCatalog?

Comment: it is workin in ArcGIS 9.3 
add data icone -> and choose GIS server (Look in) -> enter http://services.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/services.